# How to set protoc's `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` by cmake?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm using cmake to generate protobuf files like this:

```
file(GLOB PROTO_FILES 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.proto 
)
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_FILES})
```

My `protoc` is v3.14 so when I use proto3 version and optional fields, I need to set `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` according to https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v3.12.0/docs/field_presence.md#protoc-invocation, how can I do it in cmake?

Answer (score 0):

Cmake 3.28 provides `PROTOC_OPTIONS` for [`protobuf_generate`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html).

If you are on a lower cmake version, maybe this [`my_protobuf_generate`](https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/blob/696d914b7e05128bcffff5d140b2506067ff9594/cmake/protobuf_gen.cmake) from github helps.